# Create Object with OneToOneField in django tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have two models: Project and Album . They are related to each other by a oneToOneField.

album/models.py:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=128)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), unique=True, default='main-gallery')
```

project/models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), unique=True)

    main_gallery = models.OneToOneField(Album, verbose_name=_('related main album'), related_name='project', unique=True)

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Project)
def create_project(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    if instance is None:
    try:
        str(instance.main_gallery)
    except Album.DoesNotExist:
        main_gallery = Album.objects.create(title=''.join((instance.title, ' - ', 'main gallery')))
```

If a Project is created an Album will be created for it as well. This works fine. But it wont work when I try to do create one in my api with django tastypie:

```
class AlbumResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Album.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'album'
        #fields = ['title','slug',]

    def dehydrate_resource_uri(self, bundle):
        return bundle.data['slug']

class ProjectResource(ModelResource):
    main_gallery = fields.OneToOneField(AlbumResource, 'main_gallery', related_name='project', full=False)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Project.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'project'
        fields = ['slug', 'title', 'main_gallery']

        authorization= Authorization()

        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']

def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    logger.debug("obj_create Bundle %s" % bundle)
    return super(ProjectResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, created_by=request.user)
```

While a "GET" on the `Project` API endpoint works, when I try to create a new `Project` over a  "POST" I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PATHvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/PATHvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 77, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/PATHvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 192, in wrapper
    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/PATHvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 397, in dispatch_list
    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/PATHvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 427, in dispatch
    response = method(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/PATHvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 1165, in post_list
    updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, request=request, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
  File "/Users/PATH/path/path/apps/api/resources.py", line 70, in obj_create
    return super(ProjectResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, created_by=request.user)
  File "/Users/PATHvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 1774, in obj_create
    bundle = self.full_hydrate(bundle)
  File "/Users/PATHvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 698, in full_hydrate
    value = field_object.hydrate(bundle)
  File "/Users/PATHvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py", line 636, in hydrate
    value = super(ToOneField, self).hydrate(bundle)
  File "/Users/PATHvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py", line 154, in hydrate
    elif self.attribute and getattr(bundle.obj, self.attribute, None):
  File "/Users/PATHvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 343, in __get__
    raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist
DoesNotExist
```

Comment: If you ever found a solution for this, please consider posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that Tastypie fails before getting to your `pre_save` receiver. According to the traceback you've pasted it fails in `full_hydrate`. The reason for this is that by default `main_gallery` is required and not given (because you assume it will be created).

Try adding `blank=True, null=True` to

```
main_gallery = fields.OneToOneField(AlbumResource, 'main_gallery', related_name='project', full=False)
```

Comment: Is there a recommended place where this `DoesNotExist` should be caught? Or somewhere to pick it up before it hits full_hydrate?

Comment: Ok but what if the relation is required, then `blank=True, null=True` doesn't make sense?

Comment: @mrmagooey You can catch it anywhere in the call chain, for instance in `obj_create`, but it's not gonna be able to do anything useful. Because the problem is more fundamental. It's trying to hydrate the relation, but the request doesn't specify which object to use. This should be handled in a Form, but the Form's don't get called until `save`, which happens after `hydrate`.